# ColdFusion regex to detect first URL without image extension

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I've been digging around stackoverflow this evening but nothing worked so far. What I'm trying to achieve is to extract URL from a string (mainly HTML) that doesn't have any image extension at the end. So if the given HTML string has URL ending with .jpg and then somewhere few lines down another URL without any image extension, regex would get that second one and stop. Alternatively it can return all the 'good' URLs, just leave out the images.

So far I've got:

```
<cfset c= reMatch('(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+##]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+##])?',htmlString)>
```

I know image detecting part should be somewhere towards the end, but had only managed to freeze the server with my attempts so far.

Sample string to match:

```
'<tr> <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 12px;"><img src="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/01/31/us/why-iowaALT/why-iowaALT-thumbStandard.jpg" /></td> <td> <h6 style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; color: ##000000; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 2px"></h6> <h1 style="font-weight: normal; font-family: georgia,"times new roman",times,serif; font-size: 23px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 4px"><a href="http://p.nytimes.com/email/re?location=InCMR7g4BCJTYuyKqXu41s2MxgEX9Okc&amp;user_id=7b8478da99b24f28abb9c2f1be86c807&amp;email_type=eta&amp;task_id=1454290534529254&amp;regi_id=0" style="color: ##004276; text-decoration: none !important;">'
```

Note: it should be ColdFusion regex version, which is at times a bit limited

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example input to match?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I have amended the question with a sample string. Please don't mind the unmatched tags.

Comment: As you said the regex for ColdFusion is limited, I won't post it as an answer, but you can give it a try: [`(?:https?|ftp)[^"]*(?<!.jpg)(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7cR4/1)

Comment: Thanks @WashingtonGuedes, but the sequence '?<!' is unfortunately not recognised by ColdFusion

Comment: This might work for you: [`(?:https?|ftp)(?:.(?!\.jpg))*?(?=['"])`](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7cR4/2) just not well performatic as the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that your code works perfectly fine about extracting valid html links and you have them stored in array. All you have to do is go through this array and find does any of urls stored in this array doesn't contain extension -if not, return this value.

```
list_of_extensions = '(bmp|jpg|png|gif)'; //you can make this list longer
for(my_url in urls){

    if(not reFind(list_of_extensions, my_url)){ // you can be more specific in this reFind call
        return my_url; // it will return first invalid url
    }
}
```

Comment: It's amazing how sometimes while trying to achieve the result in a set way you can miss on a simple work around. This idea worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to Java for what you are trying to achieve like this:

```
<!--- Java Regular Expression Pattern Object --->
<cfset local.objPattern = createObject(
    "java",
    "java.util.regex.Pattern"
    ).compile(
        javaCast( "string", '(?:https?:\/\/)[^"]*(?<!\.jpg)(?=\")' )
        )
    />

<!--- Get Pattern Matcher for your html content --->
<cfset local.objMatcher = local.objPattern.matcher(
    JavaCast( "string", local.htmlContent )
    ) />

<!--- Find Matching URLs --->
<cfloop condition="local.objMatcher.find()">
    <cfdump var="#local.objMatcher.group()# <br>">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Could be a nice approach, but in some other test cases it returned some unmatched tags too (didn't stop with the end of link).